# Storing a pointer in pthread_mutex_t

Tags: pthreads, mutex

I'm working on a project in C that involves creating a user-level thread library by overriding pthread.h.  I'm currently working on the mutex functions.

In my implementation, I store mutexes as a linked list of structs.  What I would like to do in pthread_mutex_init is store the pointer to the element that is the newly created mutex in the pthread_mutex_t mutex variable.  Is this possible, though?  Here's some of my code so you get an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
typedef struct mutexList
{
    int mid;
    struct mutexList *prevMutex;
    struct mutexList *nextMutex;
    int locked;
    struct queueItem *owner;
    struct blockedThread *blockedHead;
    struct blockedThread *blockedTail;
} mutexElement;

int mutexCounter = 0;

mutexElement *mutexHead = NULL;
mutexElement *mutexTail = NULL;

int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *mutex, const pthread_mutexattr_t *attr)
{
    mutexElement *newMutex = (mutexElement *) malloc(sizeof(mutexElement));

    fprintf(stdout, "***LOG: Creating new mutex.\n");

    if(newMutex == NULL)
        return ENOMEM;
    newMutex->mid = mutexCounter;
    mutexCounter++;
    newMutex->locked = 0;
    newMutex->nextMutex = NULL;
    newMutex->blockedHead = NULL;
    newMutex->blockedTail = NULL;

    if(mutexHead == NULL)
        mutexHead = newMutex;

    if(mutexTail != NULL)
        mutexTail->nextMutex = newMutex;

    mutexTail = newMutex;

    mutex = (&newMutex);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your general idea can work, but there are at least a few of problems with your particular example:

- your `mutexCounter` , `mutexHead` and `mutexTail` items aren't handled in a thread-safe manner (an important property for this kind of library)
- the line `mutex = (&newMutex);` is pointless - `mutex` is a parameter that is a copy of the user's argument. When your function returns, `mutex` simply ceases to exist; it doesn't get returned to the caller.
- even trying to return `&newMutex` to the user in the first place is a problem: `newMutex` is a local variable that will expire when the function returns. Storing a pointer to it in something that's supposed to live past the current function call's duration won't work.

Note that I'm not saying that the above is an exhaustive list of problems - they're just ones that jumped out off the bat.

You could make the `pthread_mutex_t` type a typedef for a `struct mutexList*` and place the value of `newMutex` (*not* the address of `newMutex`) in `*mutex` since `mutex` would be a `struct mutexList**`.  The user's `pthread_mutex_t` variable would contain a pointer to the structure that's on your linked list.

If the user neglects to call `pthread_mutex_destroy()` and lets his `pthread_mutex_t` variable go out of scope, then the `struct mutexList` element that was allocated would never be freed, but that's a user error that you can really do nothing about.

As far as mutex initialization goes, there's another big problem that you'd still need to think about - static initialization.  The user is allowed to do something like:

```
// the following is at file scope, so it has static duration
pthread_mutex_t myMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

In this case, the user doesn't need to call `pthread_mutex_init()` - in fact, it would be an error to do so. Your library will need to detect and perform whatever appropriate dynamic initialization is needed for these statically initialized mutexes on first use (or something equivalent).  And you have to do it in a thread safe manner - the first use is not only allowed to be done on arbitrary threads, one of the main use cases for these static mutexes is to permit contention on the mutex right off the bat (for example to perform more complex initialization of other static data by the first thread that happens to get to it).

To summarize, I think the general approach of keeping a container of private mutex data structures and having the user's `pthread_mutex_t` variables be essentially pointers (or some other indirect reference) to the appropriate item in the container is fine.  However, there are a lot of complex details - especially making sure your functions are thread safe - that need to be considered and designed for.

The kinds of problems that existed in the example indicate that the design so far hasn't been given nearly enough thought. That might be OK - maybe you just started on it; just don't underestimate the attention to detail you'll need to give these things.

Comment: Another issue is maybe that user-level threads cannot block on a mutex anyway, else the kernel thread running the user thread would be unable execute any other user threads?

Comment: @Martin: I never even gave any thought to how the user-level threading model would work and details on how they might block. For the purposes of this answer I just was considering how mutex data structures might be managed. At some point the library being worked on will need to interact with the the underlying system's threads somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user is free to declare their mutexes as auto variables or declare them as pointers to memory allocated from e.g. `malloc(3)`, I'm skeptical of storing the mutex structures on a global linked list -- it sounds too likely that one of them will go out of scope and lead to garbage. (Granted, users are supposed to destroy their mutexes, but I wouldn't want to trust that very far.)

Consider the following code from the `pthread_mutex_init(3posix)` manpage:

```
static pthread_mutex_t foo_mutex;

void foo_init()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&foo_mutex, NULL);
}
```

This code uses a `static`-allocated `foo_mutex`, but it could also be `auto`-allocated; when you make a new `mutexElement` and try to assign back through the `*mutex` pointer, your code won't work for this case...

That said, I think what you're looking for is pretty simple:

```
int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *m, const pthread_mutexattr_t *attr) {
    m->base_address = m;
    /* ... your other work ... */
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand this or if it's what I'm looking for.  I guess to put my question another way, I know that if I created my own implementation of pthreads, I can use the pthread_t type to store a pointer to my thread struct (or, if I wanted, some integer to identify that thread).  I want to basically do the same thing with this pthread_mutex_t type.  I tried it though, but it doesn't seem to hold the address like pthread_t does.  Hopefully this makes my question a little more clear?  Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to explain myself.

Comment: I think there's a larger problem with your code; I've included in my answer some copy-and-paste from `pthread_mutex_init(3posix)` that I think will .. well, it'll annoy you :) .. the mutex can be allocated just about anywhere, and you're not given a `**mutex` parameter, but a `*mutex` parameter -- you can't assign back through it as you've done there.

Comment: I don't uderstand either.  The basic structure of a mutex - atomic flag, owner, thread queue, whatever, are usually in kernel space.  To access them, something has to be returned to the user that creates the mutex - handle, a pointer, a user struct that gets initialized, whatever - call that thing a 'userMutex'. It may be auto, or malloced, whatever.  Presumably, the user is going to err.. use it and so letting it go out of scope on a stack is just wierd.  If the OP wants to use a pointer 'handle' to access the userMutex, what is the problem?  I'm sorry, maybe it's just me...

Comment: @Martin: [Michael might have said it better than me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10206463/377270), specifically _If the user neglects to call `pthread_mutex_destroy()` and lets his `pthread_mutex_t` variable go out of scope, then the `struct mutexList` element that was allocated would never be freed, but that's a user error that you can really do nothing about._ While it is strictly true that it _is_ a user error, the consequences of storing user-supplied pointers outside the lifetime of the variables is a risky decision to make.

Comment: @Martin: Nothing says that the user-supplied object _needs_ to be kept on a linked list. A different data structure could place less importance on the object being handled carefully by the user. (The user may figure that the mutex variable going out of scope is sufficient -- wrong assumption, but how the library is implemented can make the difference between a simple memory leak and corrupted memory.)